# Windows Store App - WinJS: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Windows' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to load a Google map into Windows Store Application. However, having a problem with a native Windows RT function: Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog. I'm guessing that the Windows namespace is out of scope, but I can't figure out now to get this function into a scope that will make the Windows namespace accessible. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: the more I think about this, the more I think it has something to do with the fact that I am loading map.html as the source for an iFrame. So the context of map.html is an iFrame, not a Windows Store App page. I guess the Windows namespace is not available from within an iFrame?

From home.html:

```
            <iframe id="getLocationFrame" src="ms-appx-web:///pages/map/map.html" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></iframe>
```

Exception:

SCRIPT5009: Unhandled exception at line 50, column 17 in ms-appx-web://76ad865e-25cf-485c-bc77-e18186bfd7ee/pages/map/map.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Windows' is undefined
File: map.js, Line: 50, Column: 17

map.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  sensor=false"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>

    <link href="/pages/map/css/map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click to get your location.</p>
    <button id="getLocation">Get Location</button><br/>
    <div id="mapcontainer"></div><br />
    <small>
        <a id="anchorLargerMap" href="" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left" target="_blank">View Larger Map</a>
    </small>
</body>
</html>
```

map.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/map/map.html", {

    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        //Button "getLocation" event handler
        function getLocationClickHandler(eventInfo) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var mapcontainer = document.getElementById("mapcontainer");
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapcontainer, myOptions);

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationFail);
            }
        }

        var namespacePublicMembers = {
            locationSucessFunction: locationSuccess,
            locationFailFunction: locationFail,
            getLocationClickEventHandler: getLocationClickHandler
        };

        WinJS.Namespace.define("mapPage", namespacePublicMembers);
        var getLocationButton = document.getElementById("getLocation");
        getLocationButton.addEventListener("click", getLocationClickHandler, false);

        function locationSuccess(position) {
            var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: initialLocation,
                map: map,
                title: "You are here."
            });

            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&markers=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
            $("#anchorLargerMap").attr('href', url);
        }

        function locationFail() {
            var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Could not find you!", "").showAsync;  -- ********* THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION *********
        }
    }
});
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Code that is executed in the web compartment - your URL says that's where this code is - cannot access WinRT components. You'll need to use postMessage etc to communicate between the two security contexts.

Comment: Dominic - thank you very much. postMessage is the key. I'd vote you up but I don't have enough points.

Comment: I used code from this dZone blog to find the solution:  http://css.dzone.com/articles/use-winjs-post-message-iframe

Answer (score 3):

from Map.js:

```
        function locationFail() {
            //Can't do this due the the iFrame container
            //var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Could not find you!", "").showAsync;
            window.parent.postMessage("Could not find you!", "*");
        }
```

from Home.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {

        window.addEventListener("message", messageReceived, false);

        function messageReceived(e) {
            if (e.origin === "ms-appx-web://76ad865e-25cf-485c-bc77-e18186bfd7ee") {
                var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(e.data, "");
                md.showAsync();
            }
        };
    }
});
})();
```

I got the solution from this blog: http://css.dzone.com/articles/use-winjs-post-message-iframe